# Product of this dependent martingales is also a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_n$ be a filtration and $A$ and $B$ two **dependent** events. Define the two following martingales:

$$X_n = \mathbb{E}[1_A\mid \mathcal{F}_n]\quad \mbox{ and } \quad Y_n = \mathbb{E}[1_B\mid \mathcal{F}_n]$$

Is it true that $X_nY_n$ is also a martingale with respect to the same filtration?

---

Using basic properties of conditional expectations we have
$${\color{blue}{\mathbb{E}[}}X_nY_n\color{blue}\mid  { \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]} = \color{blue}{\mathbb{E}\{} \mathbb{E}[1_A\mid \mathcal{F}_{n}]\mathbb{E}[1_B\mid \mathcal{F}_{n}]\color{blue}\mid { \mathcal{F}_{n-1}\}}  = $$

$$=\color{blue}{\mathbb{E}\{} \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[1_A\mid \mathcal{F}_{n}]1_B\mid \mathcal{F}_{n}]\color{blue}\mid {\mathcal{F}_{n-1}\}} =  \mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{E}[1_A\mid \mathcal{F}_{n}]1_B\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}\} = E[X_n1_B\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$$

I'd like then to pull $X_n$ out of the expectation as $\mathbb{E}[1_A\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$ to prove the claim, but as $X_n$ and $1_B$ are not independent, I can't split this into a product of expectations.

---

I don't believe that any product of correlated martingales with respect to the same filtration is also a martingale, but I hope the fact that my martingale is exactly a contitional expectation might help.

Context: In an article with variables like these, the author said "Then using martingale convergence theorem the result follows", implicitely saying this product is also a martingale.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $X_n$ and $Y_{n-1}$ dependent?

Comment: They could be. 

The article was proving FKG's inequality on a specific type of percolation model. Essentially it was showing that any "increasing events" (on the context of that model) are positivelly correlated. On that context usually $X_n$ and $Y_{n-1}$ will be dependent.

Comment: The reason I asked: $E\{ X_nY_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1} \}=E\{Y_nE\{X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1},Y_n\}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}\}$. (if I am getting it right)

Comment: You may be reading too much into the sentence you quoted.  Because $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are bounded martingales, each converges a.s. and in $L^1$, hence the product $X_n Y_n$ also converges a.s. and in $L^1$ (the latter by a triangle inequality argument).